# Solucionar Pilas en C

Tags: c, pilas

Recien hoy me enseñaron Pilas en C, y no tengo mucha idea todavia que puedo y que no puedo hacer.
Alguien podria decirme por qué me guarda el ultimo valor que ingreso en una sola de las dos pilas extra que hice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pila.h"

int main()
{
    int x, nota;
    Pila pBase, pApro, pDesa;
    inicpila(&pBase);
    inicpila(&pApro);
    inicpila(&pDesa);


    for(x=1;x<=4;x++){
        printf("Ingrese la nota: ");
        scanf("%i",&nota);
        apilar(&pBase, nota);
    }

    if(nota<=6){
        apilar(&pDesa, desapilar(&pBase));
    }
    else if(nota>=7){
        apilar(&pApro, desapilar(&pBase));
    }

    printf("Pila Base");
    mostrar(&pBase);

    printf("Pila Aprobados");
    mostrar(&pApro);

    printf("Pila Desaprobados");
    mostrar(&pDesa);


    return 0;
}
```

No se que puede ser, y la verdad no encuentro el error.

Tal vez sea algo sencillo, pero no puedo darme cuenta.

Agradeceria si alguien me dice que tiene :D

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender tu pregunta ... el código que muestras hace justo eso, guarda el último dato en una u otra pila O-O

Comment: @Juanjo, como hago entonces para que me saque todos elementos de pBase y los deje si es menor/igual que 6 los ponga en pDesa y si es mayor/igual que 7 los ponga en pApro?

Comment: Pues ... ¿ Has intentado meter ese `if( ) ... else ...` **dentro** del `for( )` ? Justo después de llamar a `apilar( &pBase, nota );`

Comment: Me voy a hacer un harakiri... Antes no me habia servido, ahora si. Gracias @Juanjo :D